# Window still works in the background

Tags: vb6, basic

I am Trying to run in the background window
When he becomes inactive window and , i want 
that Still work and Recognizes the pressing Of The keyboard
I use Visual Basic version 6
Can it be done

My simple Code:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer) 
    If KeyCode = 37 Then 
        MsgBox ("The left arrow was pressed") 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily a Windows program receives messages only for its own windows. What you might try is installing a [journaling hook](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Hooks/Journal_Record_Hooks/article.html) to see messages for all top-level windows. This requires some care and attention so tread carefully.